# Reactive5 flatMap observeValues block did not call

Tags: ios, swift, flatmap, reactive

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    commitButton.reactive.controlEvents(.touchUpInside).flatMap(.latest) { (button) -> Signal<Bool, NoError> in
        return self.createSignInSignal()
    }.observeValues({
        // did not call
        print("Sign in result: \($0)")
    })
}

func signin(name: String, password: String, result: ((Bool)->Void)) {
   ...
}

// create SignIn Signal
private func createSignInSignal() -> Signal<Bool, NoError> {
    let (signInSignal, observers) = Signal<Bool, NoError>.pipe()

    self.signin(name: nameTextField.text!, password: passworkTextField.text!, result: ({success in
        observers.send(value: success)
        observers.sendCompleted()
    }))

    return signInSignal
}
```

When click login button, FlatMap observeValues block did not call. When I use map, It work well, I know the difference between map and flatmap, How can I let the code work using flatmap?